# AWS API Gateway Authorizer does not authorize non-default Cognito User Pool App client tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have created a new app client in Cognito, the tokens from the default app client are marked as valid by the API Gateway but not the token from the new App Client.

The API Gateway responds with HTTP 401 - UnAuthorized.

This should work because both the app clients have full permissions to the underlying users stored in Cognito.

I couldn't find any relevant documents explaining this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was linking my AWS User pool to Amazon Alexa Smart Home Skill using this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-cognito-for-alexa-skills-user-management/.

On successfully linking the skill, Alexa would only send the accessToken in the subsequent API's.

The AWS API Gateway authorizers only check for the ID token and will deem the request invalid if it is given an AccessToken.

Thus, the requests were failing. It has nothing to do with default or non-default app clients.

Using a Cognito custom authorizer seems the best option, will disable API Gateway authorization.